# getting empty value from this.props.match.params while it is showing in the react dev tools

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-redux, react-router-redux

Hi I am trying to access my params from my react router but it always shows me an empty object.

this is my code:

```
    <Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' render={(props) => (<PhotoWall {...this.props}/>)}/>
    <Route path='/single/:id' render={(props) => (<Single {...this.props}/>)}/>
    </Switch>
```

I can see the value of my params in react dev tools. but i can't access it in this.props.match.params..
[image]

Comment: could you please post the code you are using to access them?

Comment: @Cleiton hey cleiton, im accessing it like this : this.props.match.params, and i keep getting null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're debugging the state of a  Component but not the component props that you are working on (there is a **State** label above the screen shot)?

Comment: You are right. I checked Params under state and it is empty. I'm not sure what I did wrong. how do i include it in props

Comment: You have the params object inside the Component state that is associated to the route, so you just need to pass it as a props to the target Component.

Comment: that's nice. have fun :)

Comment: @slimboy  Pretty sure Tarik would appreciate you marking this answer.